# Navigating through component with router gives No component factory found for ConfirmationDialogComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have implemented `canDeactivate` guard on add, edit component that displays a mat-dialog as a confirmation component. Guard works and displays the confirmation dialog when I navigate with `routerLink`. Problem is when I try to navigate from TypeScript, I get the

```
"Error: No component factory found for ConfirmationDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?".
```

Here is my routing settings.
**App-Routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService], children: []
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: EngagementComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService], children: [
      {
        path: 'engagement',
        component: EngagementSurveyComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService],
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'edit-project/:projectId',
        component: EditProjectComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService],
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'project-reports/:projectId',
    component: ProjectReportsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'project-report/:projectId',
    component: GenerateReportComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'project-participants/:projectId',
    component: ProjectParticipantsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'project-status/:projectId',
    component: EngagementStatusComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'project-responses/:participantId/:projectId',
    component: EngagementResponsesComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'news',
    component: NewsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'questionaire/:uuid',
    component: QuestionnaireComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'questionaire-thanks',
    component: QuesCompleteThankComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService]
  },
  { path: 'copy-project/:projectId', component: CopyProjectComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService] },

  { path: 'report-project-list', component: ReportProjectListComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService] }

];
```

**Component code where I am routing to other component:**

```
@Component({
        selector: 'app-engagement-survey',
        templateUrl: './engagement-survey.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./engagement-survey.component.scss']
})
export class EngagementSurveyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


        constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private projectService: ProjectListService,
                private router: Router,
                private fb: FormBuilder, private clientService: ClientService) {

                this.projectForm = this.fb.group({
                        title: [''],
                        description: ['']
                });
                this.sampleSetup = this.fb.group({
                        template: [''],
                        categoryList: this.fb.array([])
                });

                this.questionSetup = this.fb.group({
                        template: [''],
                        questions: this.fb.array([])
                });

                this.participantForm = this.fb.group({
                        participants: this.fb.array([]),
                });

        }

        ngOnInit() {

                localStorage.removeItem('secondStep');
                this.subscription = this.clientService.currentClient.subscribe(currentClientValue => {

                        if (this.isClientChanged) {
                          this.router.navigate(['/home']); **// PROBLEM HERE**
                        } else {
                          this.isClientChanged = true;
                        }
                });

                this.addCategorie(this.participants);

                this.questionList = [];
                this.projectService.loadSampleFrameTemplate().subscribe((resp) => {
                        this.templatesList = resp;
                });

                this.projectService.loadTemplateOptions(1).subscribe((resp) => {
                        this.papulateParticipants(resp);
                });


                // this.addQuestionCategorie();
                this.getProjectEmailTemplate();
                this.getDefaultQuestionSetTemplate();
        }

        ngOnDestroy(): void {
                this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }



        canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {

                if (!this.dataSaved) {
                        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
                                width: '350px',
                                data: 'Leave Site? Changes you made may not be saved? '
                        });
                        return dialogRef.afterClosed();
                } else {
                        return of(true);
                }



        }
}
```

Can deactivate guard implementation is below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
    canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean>;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate>  {

    canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): Observable<boolean> {
      return  component.canDeactivate ?   component.canDeactivate() : of(true);
    }

}
```

I have added this confirmation dialog  component in entryCompnents array in app module and also in declarations array. This works fine when I navigate away from the component using some `routerLink` directive but with `this.router.navigate('/someroute')`

Is there some difference with both way or any work around this?

Comment: I believe this is a bug on angular router level. I experience the same issue for components that are provided to router route (so no need to add them to entryComponents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ConfirmationDialogComponent into your module entrycomponents.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  exports: [

  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ConfirmationDialogComponent

  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```